# Calling API which is located in extendedApiSlice from a reducer

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-toolkit

I am applying redux-toolkit in reactJs and here is one of my slice. And here is my sample code.

```
//userSlice.js
export const userSlice = createSlice({
    name: 'userSlice',
    initialState,
    reducers: {
        updateUser: (state, action) => {
            state.userInput = action.payload; //use for control UI render
            //how to call the "getUser" in extendedApiSlice?
        },
    },
});

export const extendedApiSlice = apiSlice.injectEndpoints({
    endpoints: (builder) => ({
        getUser: builder.query({
            query: () => ({ url: 'getUser' }),
        }),
    }),
});
```

How can I call `getUser` in reducer? Since I need to call `updateUser` first to control the UI render, then call the API to save the record in DB.

Comment: Don't call the side effect function in the reducer. Dispatch the `updateUser` action first, then call `getUser` in React component.

Comment: @LinDu Actually, I have applied your recommend method in my other part. Why I would like to do this here is mainly because I want to put the workflow here so I can reuse it in other component by only dispatch the same action. If it is not a good way, then I think I will follow your method. Thanks for sharing!

Comment: Reducer functions are to be considered pure functions, so there should be absolutely no side-effects from them.

Comment: Create a custom hook to encapsulate reusable logic.